# Rx, TPL dataflow and windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, system.reactive, tpl-dataflow

Is it good idea to use Rx and dataflow with windows service working constantly?
I just wondering to use rx interval to get data from db every 5 mintes and put it to blocking collection then use Tpl dataflow to process data. Is it correct way?

**UPDATE**

I have new question. I must get items from db, validate it and execute commit on db. Even if validation return false I must execute commit too. Now, I want to get data from db in 5min interval but I don't want to have double rows in dataFlow.So maybe must I use blockingCollection to keep row Id?

Comment: It is probably one of many ways, and yes, it should work. What prevented you from just making a small proof of concept?

Comment: Serious lack of information, how could we possibly know

Comment: Anyway , way off topic, and opinion based

Comment: Actually no. Why put *anything* in a blocking collection when you have a *dataflow* block ? Just post the data to the block as it comes. Rx is meant for event processing anyway, not timers. Reading from the database should be the job of the first TransformManyBlock of your pipeline, not Rx.Second block should receive the data from the frist block and do whatever you want it to do

Comment: That said, you *can* linke observables and dataflow blocks. You can call `.AsObserver()` on a block to get an observer that can subscribe to an observable, eg `var obs=myBlock.AsObserver(); Observable.Interval(..).Subscribe(obs);`

Comment: Thanks. You pre-empt my  questions. I was wondering if the BlockingCollection is needed at all.

Comment: @dMillan I'm writing such code right now

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Rx isn't just meant for event processing. It's superb for generating events - like timers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite.

First, you don't need a BlockingCollection at all. Dataflow blocks have their own thread-safe input buffers.

Second, blocks are meant to execute using their own tasks too, which makes them appropriate for running operations like calling databases and processing their results. Rx on the other hand is meant to process event streams which is typically done using a *single* thread.

That said, you can combine Rx and Dataflow blocks. I'm using Dataflow pipelines to

Second, Rx is meant to process event streams. To do that, it typically runs on the *current* thread.

That said, you can combine Rx and dataflow blocks. Combining an Interval sequence with a block is easy :

```
var block=new ActionBlock<int>(i=>whatever(i));
var blockObs=blockObs.AsObserver();
var interval=Observable.Interval(obs).Subscribe(obs);
```

Working with the database would require more blocks. Assuming you want to process individual rows, the first block should receive the trigger, load the data and return the rows. The second block should receive the individual rows and process them.

Assuming you use Dapper to return rows as objects :

```
 var headBlock=new TransformManyBlock<int,SomeRow>(_=>
    {
        using(var con=new SqlConnection(..whatever))
        {
            var items=con.ExecuteQuery(theQuery);
            return itmes;
        }
    });

 var secondBlock = new ActionBlock<SomeRow>(row=>DoSomething(row), 
                          new ExecutionDatalfowBlockOptions{MaxDegreeOfParalelism=10});

 headBlock.LinkTo(secondBlock,new DataFlowLinkOptions{PropagateCompletion=true});

 var headObs=headBlock.AsObserver();

 Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)).Subscribe(headObs);
```

That's just a demo though. You should add code to stop the pipeline when you shutdown the server and await any pending operations to complete.

You should also add error handling code that will allow you to continue processing even if an error occurs. If an exception isn't handled, the block that threw terminates. You can handle this if you return a "wrapped" result instead, with a flag that indicates success or failure. `LinkTo` accepts a predicate that you can use to move failed messages/rows eg to a logger or discard them, eg :

```
var loggerBlock=new ActionBlock<RowWithFlag>(row=>_log.Error(...));

headBlock.LinkTo(secondBlock,linkOptions,row=>row.IsOK);
headBlock.LinkTo(loggerBlock,linkOptions,row=>!row.IsOK);
```